# Graficar en Python con matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

> Hola, he estado intentando programar un grafico animado en python y la
> verdad no lo he logrado y no he estado ni cerca, lo estoy intentando
> hacer utilizando matplotlib y numpy.
> Quisiera saber si me pueden ayudar, el contexto es el siguiente:

El desarrollo de esta tarea pondra en practica los conocimientos adquiridos en este curso, ası como en los
cursos previos. La capacidad de resolver este tipo de problemas presentados, refuerza y/o incrementa su
destreza en la resolucion de problemas de Ingenierıa Civil. Por otra parte, las ecuaciones y los analisis
necesarios para resolver esta tarea, son ampliamente utilizados en las aplicaciones reales de la Ingenierıa
Hidraulica. Para esta tarea puede utilizar cualquier lenguaje de programacion que le permita desplegar y
graficar los resultados.
El problema consiste en calcular la fuerza resultante y su punto de aplicacion sobre una superficie inclinada
que rota en torno a su centroide y que adem´as se encuentra inmersa en una estratificacion de dos fluidos.
Incluya el diagrama de presiones (de manera grafica) asociado a la superficie. El hecho de que el problema
sea generico, implica que usted debera implementar un codigo que sea valido para cualquier espesor de los
estratos, ademas debe genera una animacion que varıe en funcion del angulo θ de inclinacion de la superficie,
desde 0 a π/2. La posicion relativa del centroide debe estar siempre en la interfase de los 2 estratos. Adem´as,
muestre gr´aficamente la fuerza resultante (como un vector) y su punto de aplicaci´on (perpendicular) sobre
la superficie para cada θ. De igual forma, grafique la distribuci´on de presi´on asociada a la superficie. Los
fluidos son agua (ρw = 1000 [kg/m3
]) y un fluido desconocido (ρd = 3500 [kg/m3
]). Considere la siguientes
condiciones geom´etricas para resolver el problema:
h2 >
L
2
y h1 <
L
2.

```
Las fórmulas que hay que utilizar son estas: 

Vector Lado Derecho:

Punto de inicio
coordenada en x = (L/2 * cosθ - (M1)*sen(θ))
coordenada en y = (-h1 + L/2 senθ + (M1)cos(θ))

Punto final
(x,y) = (L/2 cos(θ); -h1 + L/2 senθ)
M1 = r*h = 9810(h1 - L/2 * senθ)

Vector Lado Izquierdo:

Punto de inicio
coordenada x = -L/2 cos(a) - M2*sen(a)
coordenada y = -h1 - L/2 sen(a) + M2 * cos(a)

Punto final
(x;y) = (-L/2 cos(a);-h1 - L/2 sen(a))
M2 = 9819*h1 + 34335(L/2 sen(a))

Y debería quedar algo como el video en este enlace: https://drive.google.com/file/d/16SeuB_dxVLDUZI41CqqB7ILqSNtPZMp5/view?usp=sharing

por favor, les ruego su ayuda.
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El código es más importante que un enunciado. En otras palabras, crea un [mre] por favor.

Comment: *y no he estado ni cerca* El formato del sitio (y su comunidad) no está diseñado para dar guias, si no respuestas a preguntas concretas, especificas. Te recomiendo recurrir a otro sitio o hacerte con un poquito de reputación y entrar a nuestro chat